# OData V4 - Expand and options (filter, top, ...)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm using OData V4 with ASP WebApi. I would filter an expanded collection as the new version of OData can do (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html - Example 90) but in my case the filter option has no effect.

I also tried to do the same thing with the Nortwhind service and the TripPin service. It works for the TriPin service, but not for Northwind service.

Here, the requests that I used :

**My Service** : *api/odata/Customers(19037)?$expand=orders($filter=id+eq+1796)* --> **Doesn't work**

**Northwind Service** : *http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders($filter=OrderID+eq+10643)* --> **Doesn't work**

**TripPin Service** : *http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Trips($filter=TripId+eq+1001)* --> **Does Work**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to be clear. Northwind Service is implemented using WCF data services and TripPin is implemented directly using ODL.

Comment: In some cases the use of the operator `$expand` is used to circumvent the OData limitations in terms of aggregation. For this kind of need, you can use my product [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) which allows to expose an aggregation query via standard OData operators as `$select` and `$filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature we don't support for now.

The root cause is that the inline $filter is ignored while translating $expand.

Check method "GetPropertiesToExpandInQuery" of SelectExpandBinder.cs:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/Expressions/SelectExpandBinder.cs

Only `expandItem.SelectAndExpand` is returned while other options are ignored.

So only $select and $expand inside $expand work for now.

I have investigated how to fix it before, but since the issue is not approved,
please vote the issue Jinfu opened to draw more attention of lead team.

Comment: An issue was already open, https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2046. Thanks Jinfu, Zhao for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the issue, and found $select inside a $expand works well. I believe this is a defect and opened a bug for it: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2070.